# Gaining reputation for edits past your 1k cap

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, reputation

As per [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), you get +2 reputation per suggested edit that gets approved, to a cap of 1000 reputation gained. I long since reached the cap, and was surprised to see that recently I did gain +2 reputation for a suggested edit that got approved.

[image]

The edit that had been approved before the edit in question, and the edit approved after the edit in question did not result in a change of reputation, which is what I would expect.

In the days between that no approved edit of mine got deleted, altough I doubt deletions get substracted from your 1k cap. So was there a bug going on, or was this behaviour intended?

The reputation of this edit has since been retracted, by the post being deleted. For reference here the link to the now deleted post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575885/vba-organizing-calls-conditional-export-of-worksheets-into-pdf (10+K only)

**Edit:** On December 1, the +2 rep got revoked by post deletion as mentioned above. A subsequent approved edit, December 4, did not result in a reputation gain, as would be expected.

[image]

Comment: What does the last line of https://stackoverflow.com/reputation say for you? *earned ... reputation from suggested edits*

Comment: earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits

Comment: Even an edit I made after the 2 rep fromt hat edit was revoked did not result in gaining 2 rep again, as per edited in screenshot.

Comment: most likely one of the posts you edited in the past has been deleted, taking away +2 you gained from it and system retroactively "re-filled" that gap by a rep from some other old edit

Comment: @gnat I can assure that inbetween the october 24 edit, and the edit that resulted in a gain of +2, no older edit has been removed. According to my reputation overview. Or there would be a caching of 6-8 weeks involved?

Comment: It could be that after the old deletion, the next approved suggestion will apply the +2, instead of it going retroactively to something in the past?

Comment: @ryanyuyu there was an edit in between them, so that wont be the case.

Comment: After a suggestion is approved or rejected, the OP can override that with an alternative decision; perhaps that's what happened

Comment: @Justin thx for the suggestion, but I can't see how that would end up in me gaining reputation

Comment: The idea is that you had an approved edit that the OP overrode to reject, so you lose the reputation for the edit, which means you can now gain reputation for a suggested edit.

Comment: Interesting theory, but that would also result in 2 rep being substracted prior to my edit being approved, which hasn't been the case in at least 6 to 8 weeks..

Comment: @Cœur *hmm ... someone just took away that 1 rep I had on this question. Let me go rollback that change ...* Let the rollback wars begin.

Comment: @NisargShah you're correct. Possible suggestion improvement: "__+1 rep while there is no other editor since your first edit__" Could this give incentive for better edits?

Comment: @Cœur Personally, I dislike the idea of giving out rep as an incentive for any activity other than posting good questions or answers. Also, with the rep calculation process being as complicated as it is right now, I don't think such a proposal might be accepted. I might even favor taking back the +2 of an edit if someone has to improve or rollback it within, say, 5 minutes. But again, I don't think complicating such matters is a good idea.

Comment: Congratulations, you're the first person on SO to ever complain about *gaining* reputation -- I suggest a gold badge for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "bug" here is that you didn't actually earn *any* reputation from the edit in question. You originally gained 0 reputation from it because you were capped by the limit, and your reputation didn't change when it was recalculated after the post was removed either (because you hadn't actually gained anything originally).

The problem here is that once the post is deleted and no longer affects your reputation, the system frankly stops caring whether you earned reputation from it or not. The two events that are now considered "deleted" just show the normal amounts of reputation you would have gained from them (+2 and -2 respectively) without considering any caps because, well, who cares? They're deleted. They don't affect your reputation anymore.

Trying to consider all deleted events when generating your full history with those events included is probably too intense of an operation and just not worth the extra resources for additional information that results in a net effect of 0. The system does the same thing for other types of votes which have been retracted too, even if they were originally different values (like a +9 for an upvote) when they were originally cast.